# How to implement Localization ASP net CORE MVC

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I cannot figure how to work with Localization on an ASP.NET Core MVC website :
I've follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.0) website but I think I forgot something :

**Startup :**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.AddMvc(
                config =>
                {
                    config.Filters.Add<ActionFilter>();
                })
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(option =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr"),
                };
                option.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fr", uiCulture: "fr");
                option.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                option.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

**HomeController :**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

            public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
                {
                    _localizer = localizer;
                }
    public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View()
            }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["Home"];
}

<h1>News</h1>
<h2>@Localizer["Home"]</h2>
```

And I have a `Resources Folder` with a file `HomeController.fr.resx` inside where Home => Accueil relation is defined.

The function `Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.Name` return `fr` but the page always display `Home` instead of `Accueil`.

Am I missing something to do for the localization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure why it's not working, I just forget to add the Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers NugetPackage.